# Clear and re-draw figure after button clicked

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I am using "for" loop to draw my data in an interactive manner after button clicked, it gets new value and calculate data and then plot it. my problem is that after I am entering the new value, plot history is not clear and new/old plot are shown in the output, which is not suitable. How can I clear and redraw my plot data:

```
p = figure(plot_height=600, plot_width=700,x_axis_type="datetime", title="Plot Data", toolbar_location=None, tools='')
p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.legend.orientation = "vertical"
p.legend.click_policy = "hide"  # hide legend by clicking on legend entry
#p.title.text = ('Click on legend entry to hide related line')
p.legend.border_line_color = 'green'


def plot_update(X,Y,legend,pallete):
    reset_output()
    for (col, leg, x, y) in zip(pallete, legend, X, Y):
        my_plot = p.line(x, y, color=col, legend=leg, line_width=2)
    return p
```

Comment: How are you displaying the plot?

Comment: you should use ColumnDataSource, and update the data in it.